# C - Creating an anonymous struct instance

Tags: c, struct, compound-literals

In [this code](https://github.com/rui314/8cc/blob/master/lex.c), a structure is defined as follows:

```
typedef struct
{
    int line;
    int column;
} Pos;
```

And later used this way:

```
Pos get_pos ( int delta )
{
    ...

    return ( Pos ){ f->line, f->column + delta };
}
```

The line, `return ( Pos ){ f->line, f->column + delta }` seems to be creating an anonymous instance of the struct `Pos` with initialized values. What is this technique called and how does it work? Where can I learn more about it?

Comment: "Compound literal", since C99.

Comment: [C11 Standard - 6.5.2.5 Compound literals](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.5)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compound-literals+c?sort=votes  . There doesn't seem to be a canonical question, maybe this could be it

Comment: Thanks! Updated the question tag accordingly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is called a **compound literal**, and is documented in section 6.5.2.5 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).

An excerpt of this section is as follows:

> *3* A  postfix  expression  that  consists  of  a  parenthesized  type  name  followed  by  a  brace- enclosed  list  of  initializers  is  a
>   *compound  literal*.  It provides  an  unnamed  object  whose value is
>   given by the initializer list.
>
> *4* If  the  type  name  specifies  an  array  of  unknown  size,  the  size  is  determined  by  the initializer  list  as  specified  in 
>   6.7.9,  and  the  type  of  the  compound  literal  is  that  of  the completed array type.  Otherwise (when the type name specifies an
>   object type), the type of the compound literal is that specified by
>   the type name.  In either case, the result is an lvalue.
>
> *5* The  value  of  the  compound  literal  is  that  of  an  unnamed  object  initialized  by  the initializer  list.  If  the  compound 
>   literal  occurs  outside  the  body  of  a  function,  the  object has
>   static  storage  duration;  otherwise,  it  has  automatic  storage 
>   duration  associated  with the enclosing block.

In your case the compound literal is for a `struct`, but they can be created for arrays as well.  Paragraph 8 gives an example:

> *8*  EXAMPLE 1    The file scope definition
>
> ```
> int *p = (int []){2, 4};
> ```
>
> initializes `p` to  point  to  the  first  element  of  an  array  of 
>   two  ints,  the  first  having  the  value  two  and  the second, 
>   four.  The  expressions  in  this  compound  literal  are  required 
>   to  be  constant.  The  unnamed  object has static storage duration.

Note also that a compound literal is an lvalue, which means you can take its address:

```
Pos *p = &( Pos ){ f->line, f->column + delta };
```

This object has a lifetime associated with its scope, meaning that once the scope ends the object no longer exists.  So don't carry around its address after it goes out of scope.

You can also use a compound literal with a **designated initializer**:

```
return ( Pos ){ .line=f->line, .column=f->column + delta };
```

Comment: So it applies to all type (not only aggregates)?

Comment: @SomeName As it turns out, yes.  `int x = (int){4};` compiles, although there's not much use in using it for basic types.